# Experimental data on the speed of heat

Tags: thermodynamics, phonons, dispersion

I know about the speed-of-information problem tied with the solution of the heat equation (diffusion equation) for the propagation of heat via conduction. Due to the quantum-statistical nature of electromagnetic interactions/phonons it's maybe hard to speak about the true speed of the propagation of thermal energy, because what we really measure is the evolution of temperature gradient across the material. (You may correct me on that.)

Do you know about some historical records or notable experiments which were intended to compare the actual conduction of heat with a theoretical one predicted by the heat equation? I would be interested also if there had been some comparisons of the speed of sound in the given material to the measured speed with which the first detected thermal phonons arrived at the sensor after heating up a specified distance across the material.

Or, in the best case, do you know about some experiments intented to measure if and what kind of a dispersion relation $n(\omega)$ exists not only for light but also for the conducted heat phonons?

Comment: I don't understand this question. You start off with a correct statement (heat conduction is via the evolution of the temperature gradient, and there is no such thing as the 'speed of propagation of heat') and then you build a stack of questions based on its negation. Thus, for example, dispersion relations exist for wave phenomena that admit solutions of the form $e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$, which is not the case for the heat equation (unless you allow complex-valued $\omega$s), so the concept is not applicable.

Comment: I am asking for an experiment which measured an increase of the temperature in a given distance from a heat source by even the slightest bit. I am not sure whether these experiments are even useful.

Comment: The problem is in the qualifier 'even the slightest bit' ─ how small a "bit" would you need to call the propagation as having happened? What if you update your apparatus to a thermometer with a better resolution ─ would you say that the 'speed of heat' has changed?

Comment: Yes and no, is there theoretically (and was it achieved) a precision at which we could say that "no heat arrived" to some point of the crystal lattice - at all - after a given time? Even if the heat equation always gives a non-zero temperature rise everywhere after an arbitrary short time?